# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 63 (char 62)

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a program that downloads jokes from the chuck norris database:

```
import sys, webbrowser, requests, bs4, json, subprocess

def main():
        for num in range(1,100):
                res = requests.get("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/")
                res.raise_for_status()
                obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, features="html.parser")
                obj = str(obj)
                obj = json.loads(r""+ obj)
                print(obj["value"]["joke"])
                joke = obj["value"]["joke"]
                string = '{ "joke":"' + str(joke) + '" }'
                file = open("chuck.json", "w")
                file.write(string)
                file.close()
                numero = str(num)
                subprocess.call('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @chuck.json http://localhost:9200/jokes/_doc/' + numero + '?pretty')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For some reason, every time that I try to run the script, it works nicely for some time, until it just stops and outputs:

```
 File "chuck.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "chuck.py", line 9, in main
    obj = json.loads(r""+ obj)
  File "C:\Users\Joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Joaoa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 63 (char 62)
```

The weird part is that it runs during some time and even uploads the database, but it stops ramdonly for no reason. Any help?

Comment: Try catching the error and print out `obj` when it occurs. An preferably `obj` before you call `str` on it. That might help you figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The page you are requesting is "application/json", not HTML. You can read the json directly from the requests object. There is no need to get the BeautifulSoup HTML parser involved.

```
import sys, webbrowser, requests, subprocess

def main():
        for num in range(1,100):
                res = requests.get("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/")
                res.raise_for_status()
                obj = res.json()
                print(obj["value"]["joke"])
                joke = obj["value"]["joke"]
                string = '{ "joke":"' + str(joke) + '" }'
                file = open("chuck.json", "w")
                file.write(string)
                file.close()
                numero = str(num)
                subprocess.call('curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @chuck.json http://localhost:9200/jokes/_doc/' + numero + '?pretty')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: NOTE: there is a small mispelling in the code above, it isn't "jsoin()" is "json()"